# Custom widgets to pick image from gallery or camera

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i'm trying to create a custom widget that allow my users to select an image from the gallery or from the camera. This custom widget is add it dinamically to a form. All examples that i saw, all of them the class extends from Activity, so they can use onActivityResult override method, but my class extends from LinearLayout.

Theres's any way to use an image picker without using onActivityResult method?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Extending linearlayour is pretty weird, as it's just used for the "view" part, so nothing business related. You're probably putting too much responsibilities into a single component, and an Activity is the good place for what you wanna do.

Comment: Hi C4stor, thanks for your answer. I need to create dynamically this controls a put it on an activity to gather some information. In one activity may have 2 or 3 of this custom widget.